# JavaFx menu item accelerator Javafx css

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I have tried to iconified JavaFX menu item label. I got the icon duplicated for both menu item label and accelerator label.
Here is an image that illustrates my issue.

[image]

Here is the Javafx css code:

```
.menu-item > .label {

}

#miRestore .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("/img/Upload_16x16.png");
}
#miBackup .label {
    -fx-graphic: url("/img/Flash%20Disk_16x16.png");
}
#miClose .label {
    -fx-graphic: url("/img/Delete_16x16.png");
}

#miSettings .label {
    -fx-graphic: url("/img/Settings_16x16.png");
}

#miRegistre . label{
    -fx-graphic: url("/img/Help_16x16.png");
}
```

Comment: Evidently, a MenuItem internally uses a second Label to hold its accelerator text.  Changing your selectors to use `.label:first-child` might work.

Comment: @VGR, unfortunately, this not works for me at all. Even the menu icon disappears.

Comment: A reliable approach is to set your MenuItem graphic to a Node with a custom [style class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getStyleClass--), and use that in your CSS instead of (or in addition to) `.label`.

Comment: According the the [JavaFX CSS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), "The structural pseudo‑classes are not supported."  Which explains why the [`:first-child`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-child) would not work.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a reliable solution to this:
in Scene Builder / FXML (whatever you prefer),
attach a Style Class (not id) to every menu-Item you want to have an icon.
Now add a stylesheet to the menubar in which you put the following CSS for every item with an icon:

```
.yourClassName > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("yourImageUrl");
}
```

At the end of the CSS file, add the following to remove all the second images:

```
.context-menu .accelerator-text{
    -fx-graphic: none;
}
```

What this does is set the -fx-graphic of every -accelerator-text to 'none'. So it basically removes the image again.

Now you will only have icons in front of your menu-Item Text, not the accelerator text.
To give you a concrete idea on how this is done I have made a small example for you:
[image: sample]

which is the result of following CSS stylesheet added to my menubar, 
and corresponding CSS Style Classes added to my menu-Items:

```
.newIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/file.png");
}
.openIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/folderEmpty.png");
}
.closeIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/minus.png");
}
.saveIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/save.png");
}
.saveAsIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/folder.png");
}
.quitIcon > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("px16/error.png");
}
.context-menu .accelerator-text{
    -fx-graphic: none;
}
```

This was my first answer here on StackOverflow, I hope this will be helpful to someone.